# "EGL Error : could not create the EGL surface: error 0x300b" on i.MX6 when running Qt5 application with -platform eglfs

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, egl, imx6

I am trying to run the `hellogl_es2` Qt example without X Server by specifying the eglfs platform:

```
./hellogl_es2 -platform eglfs
EGL Error : Could not create the egl surface: error = 0x300b

Aborted (core dumped)
```

CPU is Freescale i.MX6.

Linux kernel is 3.10.17.

Distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty).

Qt version is 5.2.1, installed from http://packages.ubuntu.com, armhf architecture, packages qtbase5-dev, qtbase5-examples, qtbase5-examples-dbg.

The core dump is:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from hellowindow...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 19681]
[New LWP 19683]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./hellowindow -platform eglfs'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0xb66168e6 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb66168e6 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0xb6624f0e in raise () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#2  0xb6627766 in abort () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#3  0xb6902372 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /usr/local/Qt-5.2.1/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0xb62599fc in ?? () from /usr/local/Qt-5.2.1/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) q
```

The behavior is the same with other Qt example projects.

I tried to remake Qt from sources with or without applying this patch:
https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/66349/
but with no result (same error).

Comment: First thing to suggest would obviously be *upgrade everything*.

Answer (score 1):

I had This problem With qt 5.2 on Cubieboard A10 and fixed it by compiling from source and changing qeglfshooks_stub.cpp according to this tutorial 
[Qt On Cubieboard](http://www.eliasing.com/cubieboard2/qt5-cb2)

Hope This helps